# How To Send int List To View From Controller without Using View Data Or View Bag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to Send int List From Controller To View  in Asp.net Mvx Without Using Of viewData or viewBag?  just by passing The Array In

```
var numbers= new List<int>{1,2,3,4,3};
return view(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a model to the view, which contains a `List<int>`, and then add the list to the model when calling `view()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a model which contains the list of numbers.

```
public class MyModel
{
   public List<int> MyNumbersList { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your controller inside your action you can do

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var numbers = new List<int> {1, 2,3, 4, 5};
   var model = new MyModel { MyNumbersList = numbers };

   return View(model);
}
```

In your view you need to accept the model as

```
@model MyModel
```

Then to use the `List<int>` do

```
foreach(var items in Model.MyNumbersList)
{
   //do something with items
}
```